# Cannot find name ... when attribute, but not when extends

Tags: typescript

Recently I've been struggling to create large TypeScript modules, and there's something that I really don't understand. Basically, the following doesn't work :

```
// file A.ts
export = class A {

}

// file main.ts
import A = require('./A');

class B {
    a : A; // Cannot find name A
}
```

But the following does work

```
// file A.ts
export = class A {

}

// file main.ts
import A = require('./A');

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

How come in one case, it finds the `A` class and in the other one it doesn't ? Am i missing something about how we define attributes in classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually [a known issue in the TypeScript compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6377), though it may be by-design.

If you really need to use a root export you can change your class expression to a class declaration like so

```
class A {
}

export = A;
```

and that should work.

However, as [Vadam mentioned as a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35159280/4386952), you should really use ES6-style exports.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to try and analyze what's wrong with your exports and imports, life's too short for that, but this is the proper way to do it:

```
// file A.ts
export class A {}

// file main.ts
import { A } from './A';

class B extends A {
  a: A; // go nuts!
}
```

Now, if you wanted `class A` to be the default export, you'd do this instead:

```
// file A.ts
export default class A {}

// file main.ts
import A from './A';

class B extends A {
  a: A; // woooh!
}
```